# are there any states where teenagers sending nudes to each other isn't a crime?

Tags: united-states, child-porn

For the recent surveys on law enforcement it appears that it is a crime in many states with many having explicit laws against it however are there any states where this isn't a crime and what about states that don't have an explicit law against it ?

Comment: Can you quote a corresponding law? I think sending of nude pics of oneself to a girl/boyfriend is never a crime. Publishing them on social media or using them for blackmailing is.

Comment: “Teenager” by any reasonable definition would be 13 to 19 years old. I would be sure there are some places where 13 year olds are too young to be held criminally liable, and places where 19 year olds are free to send photos of themselves (as 19 year olds) as they please.

Answer (score 3):

Blaire Bayliss reviews the law in "[The Kids are Alright : Teen Sexting, Child Pornography Charges, and the Criminalization of Adolescent Sexuality](http://lawreview.colorado.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Bayliss-_-Final.pdf)" (2020) Colorado L. Rev. 251. The article uses the term "sexting" to mean the exchange of sexually explicit messages or images between individuals using electronic messaging. When images, this can constitute child pornography under federal law.

Also (from [cyberbullying.org](https://cyberbullying.org/the-status-of-sexting-laws-across-the-united-states)),

> States that do not have a specific sexting law often rely on existing statutes when dealing with teen sexting. All states, for example, have child pornography or child exploitation laws that prohibit sending, receiving, or possessing images of a sexual nature of a minor.

Bayliss notes though that some *states* have adapted their child pornography laws to account for teen sexting:

[image]

For example, in Rhode Island, teens will not be charged under state criminal child pornography laws but may be "tried" in family court. And in Colorado, "teens who are approximately the same age and who exchange sexual images with the understanding of consent have committed a civil infraction." See [Colo. Rev. Stat § 18-7-109(3)](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-18-criminal-code/co-rev-st-sect-18-7-109.html).

Bayliss's article and map are from 2020, but [a 2022 dataset](https://cyberbullying.org/sexting-laws) by the Cyberbulling Research Center shows not much has changed. That dataset also provides links to state-specific sexting laws where they exist.

Note that no state law can exempt teens from the application of federal child pornography and related laws.

Of course, if the image does not even constitute pornography, then all of the above is irrelevant, but I understand you to be asking about the circumstance where the content is typically or historically criminalized.

Comment: At least in Europe, a picture of a nude boy/girl isn't pornography. Is this different in the US?

Comment: TL;DR this is illegal all over USA ? but is this criminalised  the same way all over ?

Comment: > of course , if the imagine does not even constitute pornography , then all of the above is irrelevant. " what do you mean ?

Comment: @IndianLawDropout That was added after my comment above. The answer is about teen sexting and child pornography. As such, I think it doesn't fully answer the question because as I read it, the OP assumes that "sending nudes" is already a crime.

Comment: @Pmf Not automatically, but it could. It would depend on the picture.